# Using the turbolinks:load event only once for a particular page?

Tags: turbolinks, turbolinks-5

I've got some code that I want to run only on one page of my app, so in my HTML I'm using the following inline JS:

```html
<script>
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    console.log("Ground control to major tom?")
  });
</script>
```

However, then when the user navigates away from that page - that code is still running on every subsequent visit.

How can I use the turbolinks:load event only for a particular page?

Do I need to somehow 'tear down' that event handler? How would I prevent that from affecting any other turbolinks:load events that I may have?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, check if you need to run this code on `turbolinks:load`—you might not need to! `<script>`s included at the bottom of the page will have access to all DOM elements, so listening for `turbolinks:load` might not be necessary.

If you are sure you need to handle `turbolinks:load`, to tear down your handler, you have a couple of options.

**Option 1.** Used a named function, then reference that when calling `off`. (This approach would be compatible with `document.removeElementListener` too.)

```
;(function () {
  function onLoad () { console.log("Ground control to major tom?") }

  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', onLoad);

  $(document).on('turbolinks:before-render', function() {
    $(document).off('turbolinks:load', onLoad);
  });
})()
```

**Option 2.** Namespace your event. jQuery supports customised event names, so with this approach you don't need to reference the handler.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load.my-namespace', function() {
  console.log("Ground control to major tom?")
});

$(document).on('turbolinks:before-render', function() {
  $(document).off('turbolinks:load.my-namespace');
});
```

Comment: Option 2 is exactly what I needed. Thanks